# Is there any good documentation on the VB.Net Project file structure?

Tags: vb.net, file, documentation, project, specifications

I need to start messing with a vb.net(vs2008) project file and I'd like a reference to, ideally, it's specification.

Any links would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh! As I should have known....a VB.Net Project is nothing more than an MSBuild file.

Detail here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452.aspx